# Turn off link previews in messages.google.com

Tags: links, google-messages

There are dozens of guides on how to turn off link previews in Messages by Google app for Android ([one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226587/20449), [two](https://support.google.com/messages/thread/9224267/how-do-i-turn-off-link-previews?hl=en), [three](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/6080337?hl=en#zippy=%2Cturn-off-verified-sms%2Cturn-off-link-previews-for-websites)). But how do I turn them off for web / PC version available at *messages.google.com*?

Settings only allows you to decide whether you want to:

- Replace emoticons with emojis when typing
- See message content in notifications

But no sign  of anything around disabling link preview.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike almost all other Google apps, Google Messages is intended primarily for Android. The Web app is a companion, complementary app, so some features might be added later or will never be added. If it's possible to do what you are looking for, this could likely be done in the settings section of the Web app. To access this section:

1. Go to https://messages.google.com

   - If you have not paired your computer / browser, you must pair it to continue. Follow the instructions given on the screen.
   - You should see the side panel showing the More Options button (the three vertical dots)
     [image: Google Messages for the Web].
2. Click More Options > Settings
   [image: Google Messages More Options Menu].
3. If you don't find the setting that you are looking for, click Back, then More Options > Help and type a query, i.e, `preview`:
   [image: Google Messages Help with results for "preview"]

If you don't find a helpful help article, you might use web browser developer tools or a browser extension to modify the client-side code on the fly to meet your requirements.

You might search for browser extensions in the respective marketplace of browser extensions of your browser. Also you might ask for software recommendations in [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Regarding the browser developer tools, you need to know about HTML, CSS, JavaScript, [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), among other things and know about the browser menus. Knowing some keyboard shortcuts like F12 is handy. You might ask questions about how to use them in [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Please note that the More Options menu includes a Send Feedback option. This option is helpful to send your feature requests directly to Google.

---